# line gets thick when scaling

Tags: android, android-canvas

I draw a line in Android canvas with the thickness of 1 (`paint.setStrokeWidth(1)`). When scaling the canvas with `canvas.scale(2,2)`, then the line gets thicker. How can I draw the line only one pixel thick, even if I am scaling in (e.g. zooming in)?

Comment: There is no `setStrokeWidth()` method on `android.graphics.Canvas`, what method are you using exactly?

Comment: Sorry , its my fault in the description. I use the paint for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width for stroking.
Pass 0 to stroke in hairline mode. Hairlines always draws a single pixel independent of the canva's matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.htm) objects [`setStrokeWidth`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29)-method you can use the value 0 to draw a single-pixel line.

From the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29):

> Set the width for stroking. Pass 0 to stroke in hairline mode.
>   Hairlines always draws a single pixel independent of the canva's
>   matrix.